# PHP associative array filtering

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, loops

I have an associative array and I want to sum the duplicated values due to the duplicated elements in the key..

> For better explain:

```
    array:6 [
  0 => array:4 [
    "itemsName" => "H&M Chemise#15 M.Colors Orange x Grey '17(red-l)"
    "itemsQuantity" => 3
    "itemsCode" => 101
    "itemsBarcode" => "101|60|78"
  ]

  1 => array:4 [
    "itemsName" => "H&M Chemise#15 M.Colors Orange x Grey '17(green-l)"
    "itemsQuantity" => 1
    "itemsCode" => 101
    "itemsBarcode" => "101|15|78"
  ]

  2 => array:4 [
    "itemsName" => "Polo Cap Multi Colors B-Logo(red-l)"
    "itemsQuantity" => 2
    "itemsCode" => 104
    "itemsBarcode" => "104|60|78"
  ]

  3 => array:4 [
    "itemsName" => "Polo Cap S-Logo White(green-l)"
    "itemsQuantity" => 1
    "itemsCode" => 107
    "itemsBarcode" => "107|15|78"
  ]

  4 => array:4 [
    "itemsName" => "H&M Chemise#15 M.Colors Orange x Grey '17(green-l)"
    "itemsQuantity" => 2
    "itemsCode" => 101
    "itemsBarcode" => "101|15|78"
  ]

  5 => array:4 [
    "itemsName" => "H&M Chemise#15 M.Colors Orange x Grey '17(red-l)"
    "itemsQuantity" => 3
    "itemsCode" => 101
    "itemsBarcode" => "101|60|78"
  ]
]
```

> Problem:

You will find that the barcode **01|15|78** is duplicated in the array index **4 and 1** so I want to sum up the quantities in index **4 and 1** and make them a single array and it will be:

`[ "itemsName" => "H&M Chemise#15 M.Colors Orange x Grey '17(green-l)" "itemsQuantity" => 3 "itemsCode" => 101 "itemsBarcode" => "101|15|78" ]`

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets assume your array was saved under the variable `$cart`.

You can use the PHP function array_reduce to walk through each item of your array, filter it and edit the values of other indices.

```
$cart = array_reduce($cart, function($newCart, $item){
    $barCode = $item['itemsBarcode'];
    if (array_key_exists($barCode, $newCart)) {
        $newCart[$barCode]['itemsQuantity'] += $item['itemsQuantity'];
    } else {
        $newCart[$barCode] = $item;
    }
    return $newCart;
}, []);
```

If you need to have simple numeric array keys (to loop it through an for loop for example) use `$cart = array_values($cart);` afterwards.